# Equivalent of windows gdi regions in linux

Tags: windows, linux, graphics, lazarus, regions

I sometimes use windows gdi regions for graphics drawing and invalidation/validation. For example the program http://www.maxerist.net/main/soft-for-win/tubicus (oss) was made using only regions (no bitmaps or off-screen buffer). The drawing was made with FillRgn and FrameRgn, invalidation and painting with  InvalidateRgn and CombineRgn,  every cell (see screenshot) is a simple region created with CreateEllipticRgn, CreatePolygonRgn and CombineRgn.

I have plans to port it to Linux. As I understood, there are many graphics libraries in Linux. Are there ones that support windows-like regions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want to use The X Window System, a.k.a. X11, as your graphic platform. Its client library is called Xlib. The platform supports polygonal regions.

There are many libraries written on top of Xlib (Gtk, Qt, wxWindows and more) but you always can use the low-level Xlib API directly with any of them. Qt even supports elliptic regions. I don't know the details but I guess it's implemented on top of X11 polygonal regions.

Comment: Thanks, can you name something (function name maybe) in X11 related to non-rectangular regions? I searched before and could not find

Comment: @Maksee Sure. `XPolygonRegion` creates a polygonal region.

Answer (score 1):

Qt has a lot of options for painting, and using `QPainter` with [`QPainterPath`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpainterpath.html) objects might suit you well. (There are samples in the Qt distribution). You can combine (add/intersect/substact) paths.

The [`QGraphicsView framework`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview.html) is a good alternative too.